# Unable to resolve module using flowconfig

Tags: ios, react-native, flowtype

I'm trying to use flowconfig on a React Native app, but I can't find any file.

Here is an example:
.flowconfig:

```
[options]
module.system=haste
[libs]
./node_modules/flow-interfaces/interfaces/
./interfaces/
./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-interface.js
./node_modules/react-native/flow/

module.name_mapper='^reducers\/\(.*\)$' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/app/reducers/\1'
module.name_mapper='^reducers$' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/app/reducers'
```

When running:

```
Unable to resolve module reducers from ...
```

The same config works on a web project, does anyone have any idea?
Thanks! :D

Comment: You seem to have edited your `module.name_mapper` variable. Why did you do that?

In general, `.flowconfig` files are project-specific.

Comment: please add an import example